# C compiler while installing GCC!

Tags: gcc, c, compiler

I have a virtual machine running RHEL7. I am trying to install GCC from source following

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC

I am unable to do

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

or

```
yum install gcc
```

since I haven't connected to the YUM repos.

When I try to run the `./configure` I get this error:

```
No acceptable C Compiler found in $PATH.
```

How can I add a C compiler in the PATH when I am trying to install a compiler itself?

Please help me

Comment: How did you get the source for gcc on the machine without being able to copy an RPM from CentOS7?

Comment: I downloaded the gcc tar from a GNU mirror site on the RHEL7 virtual machine.

Comment: Install the (I believe it's called) "Development Tools" as package group instead of compiling your own version of GCC.

Comment: Thanks! I installed precisely that from the CentOS 7 mirror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcc (and almost any package you need from RHEL7) can be provided by CentOS7, since it is built with the same source and configuration details.  You could get that (and any needed dependencies) from CentOS's website:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped. Added this as my repository and was able to install development tools